# .clone() not working how I thought it would

Tags: jquery

When I clone something, I want to clone it as a duplicate consecutive element and add a separate identifier to it.

Doesn't work: `$(".selecter").clone().after(".selecter").addClass('.selecter2');`

jQuery should make a `.cloneAs()` or something..

What can we do about this?

Comment: Could you specify `doesn't work` a bit more?

Comment: I don't know how much clearer i can be here.. It just doesn't work. Doesn't add it to DOM, what else do you want?

Comment: Does it produce an error? Does it appear somewhere? Doe you get an object somewhere in that chain you can check (`console.log` for instance), do you even get something with that initional `$(".selecter")`, what happens when you user `.after` on something you know exists (looking at your accepted answer, if you'd tested "`after`" without clone, you'd have found out that your problem was there), etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can tell by your question, it seems like you want to use `.insertAfter` rather than `.after`.

Note also that `addClass` should contain only the class name, which presumably doesn't contain a dot.

```
$(".selecter").clone().insertAfter(".selecter").addClass('selecter2');
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PyeMx/)

Comment: Smart answer, it worked.. I still think they should add a `cloneAs()`

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what `cloneAs` would mean, but hey, glad this helped.

Answer (score 1):

`.after` inserts the content (as indicated by the argument) after each item, so I would think the above code clones `.selector` and, undesirably, adds the text ".selecter" literally after each item.

Perhaps you want

```
 $('.selecter').clone().addClass('selecter2');
```

However, while `clone` will clone the selected elements, you now have to add them somewhere.

```
 $('.destination-for-selecter').append($('.selecter').clone().addClass('selecter2'));
```

You haven't made it clear where the cloned elements will go.

Comment: Are you you just trying to duplicate each .selector in place?

Comment: I want .selecter to be cloned and then i want to add another class to it, like .selecter2

Comment: OK, so cloning in place. Well then, @DavidHedlund's answer will do.